# If you move into a lightly obscured area after hiding in a heavily obscured area, are you automatically seen?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, stealth

Is there a rule in the game for how much obscurance you need to remain hidden once you are already hidden?

If I'm a Goblin in a pitch black cave, and I am fighting an Elf who has Darkvision, and I am currently hidden due to hiding on my last turn, can I walk out from the wall I'm hiding behind and not be seen by the Elf now that there is no obstacle between us and we are within each other's Darkvision ranges?

Dim Light lightly obscures. Darkvision treats Darkness as Dim Light.

The side bar on Stealth in the PHB says "You can't hide from a creature that can clearly see you..." which is ambiguous, because something that can be clearly seen is not obscured, and this seems to be referring to the act of Hiding, and not having already Hidden. It would probably say "remain hidden" if it didn't mean "attempting to hide."

Comment: @dale-m could you please quote the relevant part which answers the OP's question?

Comment: @enkryptor Looks like a good dupe to me. Dale’s answer there provides good guidance for handling the situation described in the question, and the question here seems to be a sub-question of that one.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Reading Dale's answer to the linked question doesn't answer my question, but does link to a question that answers my question. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65799/sneaking-through-areas-people-are-watching-closely/65808#65808 For reference, I would've chosen this question's answer because it refers to the PHB as to why it is correct.