# Does Invisibility provide cover for the purpose of ending Witch Bolt?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility, cover

So I have a Warlock using Witch Bolt. For the purpose of ending the spell, does Invisibility provide full cover? If not, doesn't this mean you can use the Witch Bolt to locate the invisible creature?

It doesn't say that it does, so I ruled "no" on the spell ending and "yes" on the latter.

Comment: Is your question about the *invisibility* spell in particular, or invisibility in general (regardless of source - e.g. the [duergar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/duergar)'s ability to turn invisible once per short or long rest)? The capitalization of "Invisibility" suggests that you mean the spell, though I think the question remains the same for the general case of invisibility as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have not specified if it is the warlock or the target who is subject to the invisibility spell.

### General

In either case, invisibility does not provide cover.

In addition, being invisible does not make you hidden. To be hidden, you must have taken the Hide action and subsequently not done something to lose hidden status. Unless you are hidden, people know where you are. See [What advantages does hiding have?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63441/what-advantages-does-hiding-have/63453#63453) One thing that would cause you to loose hidden status would be to be at the end of "a sustained arc of lightning", like from, hmmm ... *Witch Bolt*

### Invisible Warlock

If the warlock is subject to an *Invisibility* spell then casting *Witch Bolt* or any other spell ends the *Invisibility* spell. Being an unseen attacker would grant the warlock advantage on the ranged spell attack.

If the warlock has already cast the *Witch Bolt* and then is the target of an *Invisibility* spell they can continue to concentrate on the *Witch Bolt* and do damage each round without ending the *Invisibility* since they are neither casting a spell or attacking. Of course, they cannot Hide without ending the *Witch Bolt* as that would take their action. If they can Hide as a bonus action or have more than one action per turn, they can Hide but would immediately lose hidden status due to being at the end of "a sustained arc of lightning"; just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

### Invisible Target

An invisible target gives you disadvantage on the ranged spell attack. In addition, if the target is also Hidden, you would need to guess its location; if you guess wrong you will automatically miss. If you are playing on a grid this would mean indicating the square your think the target is in; if not playing on a grid it would mean indicating in some other way.

On a hit, the creature would remain invisible but would not be hidden nor be able to Hide while subject to the spell.

Comment: Upvoted both, but this is a very thorough answer covering scenarios I hadn't even bothered to think about yet. Kudos.

Answer (score 10):

### No, it doesn't provide cover.

There is nothing between you and the creature, so there is nothing to provide cover.

Since the arc is continuous, that means that you would indeed be able to identify where it is.  Of course, if the creature isn't hiding, you know where they are anyway (you can hear them move or similar).