# Does Devil's Sight allow you to see in darkness as though it was normal light?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, vision-and-light

There are technically answers to this question both here, [Sage Advice](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/18/devils-sight-vision/), a tweet by Jeremy Crawford, and this question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91100/how-should-a-warlocks-devils-sight-invocation-work), but they still seem rather vague/non-descriptive enough.

> **Devil's Sight** (PHB Pg. 110)
>
> You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a
> distance of 120 feet.

But does "see normally" imply you see as though everything is naturally lit up by the sun; lit by a dim torch; still dark, but you can pick out clear images, shapes, and details; or something else entirely?

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of [How does the warlock's Devil's Sight eldritch invocation work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91100/how-should-a-warlocks-devils-sight-invocation-work) in any sense other than "you don't like the answer?"  The thing to do is bounty that question, comment, etc. not open a duplicate.

Comment: @mxyzplk I asked because I don't understand the other answer, not because I simply don't like it. I'm asking for a definitive answer, and the other question's answer isn't one that I understand, so other than re-ask the question, reference the other question, state that I still don't understand the question, and ask if someone can answer it in better terms is all I can think to do. Open to suggestions, otherwise, I suppose you're implying I'm out of luck. Other sites exist, I guess. Looks like all I can do is bounty it, then.

Comment: Then comment on an answer seeking additional clarification.  But a dupe's a dupe.

Comment: Sorry, we simply don't do re-asking. There are very important reasons for that, but I can understand that it can be frustrating.

Comment: Point of clarification: Is your core question really that you don't understand the logical mechanics of the Devil's Sight invocation? If so,that's a very difficult question to answer as you are asking for a 'better real-world explanation' of a magical effect.

Answer (score 5):

#### Devil's Sight

"You see normally" means pretty much just that. You treat all spaces within 120 feet of you as if they were brightly lit. It doesn't matter if you're standing in darkness or not. It doesn't matter if those spaces are dimly lit or not lit at all. It doesn't matter if the lack of light is magical or non-magical.

#### Darkvision

For comparison, darkvision is much weaker than Devil's Sight. You treat any *non-magically* dark spaces within range as if they were dimly lit (**not** brightly lit), and additionally you can only see shades of grey in those spaces, not color.

Answer (score -3):

"Light" (dim or otherwise) is **not** "darkness" Devil's Sight only works in "darkness". If you are in an area of light, Devil's Sight does not work **at all.**

If you are in darkness Devil's Sight allows you to see into other dark areas as though they were brightly lit. If you are looking into a lit area then you see it as the light conditions there dictate: this isn't Devil's Sight, it's just sight.