# Does the Devil's Sight eldritch invocation let me see the inside of my eyelids?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, vision-and-light, eldritch-invocations

So [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91100/how-should-a-warlocks-devils-sight-invocation-work) says that Devil's Sight only works in total darkness.

Does this then imply that the warlock can see the inside of his own eyelids with this ability?

Comment: Does this even matter? What is the purpose of seeing the inside of your own eyelids? The Devil's Sight still doesn't let you see through them.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @enkryptor, this question is at least as useful as the [one about languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97141/9552), still that one has 22 upvotes

Comment: @András I didn't ask "is this question useful". I've asked "what is the purpose". "No purpose" would be a valid answer. It's still better to say this explicitly to avoid the XY problem.

Comment: No real purpose, just shower thoughts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that seems to follow from a literal reading, though I can't think of a time it would matter.

Though, as noted in the question you linked, Devil's Sight arguably works only in total darkness. Eyelids are not completely opaque to light (and you wouldn't want them to be) so we wind up in the odd situation that the Warlock could only see his own eyelids when the light was dim enough that closing the eyes would effectively put the Warlock's eyes in total darkness.