# What are the options for a PC with cold resistance and darkvision?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, racial-traits, vision-and-light, damage-resistance

Here's what doesn't seem to work:

- Goliath (does not have darkvision)
- Mountain Dwarf (does not have cold resistance)

The only race that seems to have both is the Triton.

Any other options for a race / class combination (including Tasha's Custom Lineage or Customizing Your Origins)?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Darkvision Class Feature with Cold Resistant Race:

#### Twilight Cleric 1st level (Always on, 300 feet)

The Twilight Cleric feature Eyes of Night gives Darkvision:

> You can see through the deepest gloom. You have darkvision out to a range of 300 feet. In that radius, you can see in dim light as if it were bright light and in darkness as if it were dim light.

Paired with a cold resistant race (Goliath, Silver/White Dragonborn) gives the desired combination.

#### Way of Shadow Monk (3rd) (costs 2 ki points, lasts 8 hours)

The Way of Shadow monk can spend two ki points to cast *darkvision*, 8 hours no concentration.  The class feature is called Shadow Arts:

> Starting when you choose this tradition at 3rd level, you can use your ki to duplicate the effects of certain spells. As an action, you can spend 2 ki points to cast darkness, darkvision, pass without trace, or silence, without providing material components.

#### Warlock Invocation (120 feet, works on magical darkness too)

Warlocks can get permanent ability to see in full darkness starting at level 2, with the Devil's Sight invocation.  (But unlike normal darkvision, it *doesn't* have a benefit in dim light, [according to Jeremy Crawford's design intent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91100/how-does-the-warlocks-devils-sight-eldritch-invocation-work).)

> You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.

Alternatively, and not near as good for dealing with darkness, the Warlock gets an invocation at 7th level:

> As an action, you gain the ability to see through solid objects to a range of 30 feet. Within that range, you have darkvision if you don’t already have it. This special sight lasts for 1 minute or until your concentration ends (as if you were concentrating on a spell). During that time, you perceive objects as ghostly, transparent images.
>
> Once you use this invocation, you can’t use it again until you finish a short or long rest.

#### Gloom Stalker Ranger (3rd): Umbral Sight:

> At 3rd level, you gain darkvision out to a range of 60 feet. If you already have darkvision from your race, its range increases by 30 feet.

#### Shadow Magic Sorcerer (1st): Eyes of the Dark:

> Starting at 1st level, you have darkvision with a range of 120 feet.

#### Druid/Ranger/Sorcerer/Wizard/Artificer (2nd level spell *darkvision*, lasts 8 hours)

Any class that can cast *darkvision* yields the desired combination. The level that *darkvision* becomes available varies by class.  It's not concentration, has a cast time of 1 action, and can be cast on yourself or someone else.  It gives 60 ft range darkvision.

### Cold Resistance Class Feature with Darkvision Race:

#### Storm Herald Barbarian (Tundra) 6th level

The Storm Herald Barbarian can gain cold resistance at 6th level via the Storm Soul feature.

#### Fathomless/Fiend/Genie Warlocks

Three different Warlock subclasses give cold resistance.

Fathomless (6th level), Oceanic Soul:

> You gain resistance to cold damage.

Fiend (10th level), Fiendish Resilience:

> Starting at 10th level, you can choose one damage type when you finish a short or long rest. You gain resistance to that damage type until you choose a different one with this feature. Damage from magical weapons or silver weapons ignores this resistance.

Genie (6th level), Elemental Gift:

> You begin to take on characteristics of your patron’s kind. You now have resistance to a damage type determined by your patron’s kind: bludgeoning (dao), thunder (djinni), fire (efreeti), or **cold (marid)**.

#### Tiefling with the Infernal Consitution feat.

This one is tiefling exclusive; tieflings have darkvision, and the Infernal Constitution feat gives the resistance:

> You have resistance to cold damage and poison damage.

#### Eldritch Adept feat.

The Eldritch Adept feat allows you to select an invocation, and the Devil's Sight invocation mentioned previously is eligible.

Comment: For a weird option there is the Transmutation Wizard's Transmuter's Stone feature which grants (among other things) either 60 feet of Darkvision or resistance to cold damage. Not sure how to incorporate that in, so I listed it here

Comment: @Exempt-Medic I'll get to it.

Comment: All I can say is Wow! This should be upvoted many, many times.

Comment: @Snowcrash I’ll continue to update this as I have time and find other features. I’m currently playing a Twilight Cleric Goliath in Icewind Dale, 10/10 would recommend if your DM is okay with it.

Comment: Mind you, Devil’s Sight only gives you vision in complete darkness. Not in dim light. It’s not exactly the same as darkvision. See here: [How does the warlock's Devil's Sight eldritch invocation work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91100/how-does-the-warlocks-devils-sight-eldritch-invocation-work)

Comment: A dwarf drinking Gutbuster gets cold resistance. https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Gutbuster_(drink)

Comment: @jo1storm While that beverage seems to be canonical to the Forgotten Realms lore, it does not appear to have any mechanical basis in any edition, so I will not be including it in this answer.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I know, I just like that drink :). "However, if the drinker survived it, they were granted immunity to sleep and cold for some time."

Comment: @jo1storm I'd buy you one.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov no, thank you ;) . Quote: It was described as the "most foul-tasting concoction ever brewed." If you fail the constitution check (must have 20 or more), you get exhaustion. It is like dwarven bread to me. To be longingly looked at, but never consumed.

Comment: @jo1storm So....a jaeger bomb?

Answer (score 6):

If your DM allows, you could swap Tiefling fire resist for cold resist, like [Jester](https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Jester_Lavorre#Tiefling_Abilities) on Critical Role.  (The backstory reason was the mix of her father's traits with her mother's standard-Tiefling traits.)  Her Hellish Rebuke also deals cold damage.

Tieflings have darkvision built-in.

This is of course not strictly RAW, essentially homebrewing a Tiefling variant, but cold resist and fire resist are similar in value.  (Usually fire resist is somewhat more valuable for combat; more monsters do fire damage.  Cold resistance is nice for RP reasons in colder climates / seasons, even if your DM doesn't impose mechanical penalties on other characters, but in hot weather people with fire resist can more comfortably wear full armor.)

So there's not a big change balance-wise to making this swap, unless your campaign or one-shot are definitely set somewhere that cold resist is obviously going to be more valuable.

Comment: (I thought about just commenting to ask if non-RAW swaps like this were allowed, but it's essentially an answer.  I know it won't be useful for all readers.)

Comment: You contextualise it and back it up - it looks like a fine answer. If you'd want to, you may also link to the meta-analysis of damage resistances or similar answers and conclude that even though cold is a better damage type in that sense, it depends on GM implementation of these enemies as world-building aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Many abilities/spells grant temporary bonuses which might qualify, so for the sake of this post I am only included abilities which can be maintained indefinitely or are simply passive bonuses. Keep in mind the artificer infusions are also just magical items, so you could find those, but that's usually not up to the players.

### Gaining Darkvision:

Devil's Sight - Warlock or Feat (Eldritch Initiate) Keep in mind this works slightly different from normal darkvision.

Gloom Stalker - Ranger Subclass

Twilight - Cleric Domain

Shadow Magic - Sorcerer Subclass

Artificer - Infusion: Goggles of the Night.

### Gaining Cold Resist:

Storm Soul - Barbarian Subclass

Fiendish Resistance - Warlock Subclass

Elemental Gift - Warlock Subclass

Oceanic Soul - Warlock Subclass

Infernal Constitution - Feat, Tiefling Only.

Artificer - Infusion: Resistant Armor

Comment: This list would be more useful if you named the subclass and what level you gained the feature.  e.g. Oceanic Soul - 6th lvl Fathomless Warlock.