# Does the spell See Invisibility enable you to see a hidden creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stealth

Does the spell [See Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/see-invisibility) allow you to see a hidden creature (not one  that is invisible)?

Assume that the creature has already hidden successfully (i.e. its stealth roll beat your passive perception). Also assume that it's not behind full cover.

I assume *no* because invisible and hidden are two different things but wanted some clarification.

Ryan Thompson’s comment is also interesting in that if a creature was invisible AND hidden in plain sight (possible due to invisibility) and then someone casts see invisibility, would that now reveal them?

Comment: This seems relevant: "[What are the “rules of hidden club” for D&D 5th edition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41870)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Only if the creature is hidden solely by invisibility

Being hidden simply means that other creatures are not aware of the hidden creature's current location. This doesn't always rely purely on sight, though that is most often the method used.

> ***Stealth.*** Make a Dexterity (Stealth) check when you attempt to conceal yourself from enemies, slink past guards, slip away without being **noticed**, or sneak up on someone without being seen **or heard**. (PHB, p. 177)

If Johnny is in clear view, and is sneaking up quietly from outside Billy's field-of-view, the Stealth check made is not to see if Billy spots them; that is already not possible as they are not looking in Johnny's direction. Stealth in this situation is to see if they can move quietly, without alerting Billy to their presence. If at any time Johnny were to enter Billy's field-of-view, the Stealth roll would not matter and Johnny would no longer be hidden.

Similarly, if Billy is under the effects of *see invisibility*, this would not change the scenario, as Johnny's Stealth relies on defeating Billy's ability to hear him approach.

If Johnny is invisible, even if Billy turns around (possibly from Johnny failing his Stealth check to move quietly), Johnny is still not visible. Billy may be able to hear him, and make an attempt to attack, but Johnny would be an unseen target due to the invisibility.

There are particular class features that do produce caveats to this, but given the general scope of your question they aren't appropriate to bring up at this time.

Answer (score 6):

### [*See Invisibility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/see-invisibility) (PHB, 274)  only does what it says.

> For the duration, you see invisible creatures and objects as if they were visible, [...]

If being invisible was the *only* thing allowing a creature to successfully hide in the first place, then sure... the creature is not hidden *to the person benefiting from the spell*. They're still hidden to everybody else.

*See Invisibility* doesn't allow the recipient to see through walls or whatever else somebody may be hiding behind. Some creatures (like Wood Elves and characters with the Skulker feat) can hide in nothing more than rain.

Answer (score 3):

If they are using magic that renders them invisible then yes, they would no longer be hidden.

Assuming though since you said there is no cover, then they are not hiding behind any obstacle or living being and are in plain sight. If they are not attempting to blend into the environment in any way such as the or ranger hide in plain sight trait then they would not be hidden, otherwise they would be considered hidden.

> ([Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#Ranger))
> Starting at 10th level, you can spend 1 minute creating camouflage for yourself. You must have access to fresh mud, dirt, Plants, soot, and other naturally occurring materials with which to create your camouflage.
>
> Once you are camouflaged in this way, you can try to hide by pressing yourself up against a solid surface, such as a tree or wall, that is at least as tall and wide as you are. You gain a +10 bonus to Dexterity (Stealth) checks as long as you remain there without moving or taking Actions. Once you move or take an action or a Reaction, you must camouflage yourself again to gain this benefit. (PHB, p. 92)

**[PHB Excerpt on hiding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Initiative)**

> You can't hide from a creature that can see you clearly, and you give away your position if you make noise, such as shouting a warning or knocking over a vase. An invisible creature can always try to hide. Signs of its passage might still be noticed, and it does have to stay quiet. (PHB, p. 177)

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate.